# Does boto3 Bucket.object.filter retrieve object efficiently?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I want to get a list of all the objects(or max 1000) located at foo-bucket/foo-dir , e.g.

> Bucket: foo-bucket
>
> Directory: foo-dir

I see [Bucket.objects](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects) boto3 API use filtering(Bucket.objects.filter)

I am wondering what it does internally? Does it list all the objects and filter? Or does AWS provide an API that takes filter arguments and return the filtered results.

Comment: Please elaborate your requirements. E.g. do you want a offline full list to be used in the future, or you want to know is list_objects going to cost you dearly? Because there is a way to get offline directory list from S3  
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html

Comment: I wasn't looking for an offline directory list, I wanted to know if the filtering is done by boto or the S3 API itself.

Comment: Question fixed.   You can download the source and find your answer here : https://github.com/boto   . Or raise the question in there.  IMHO, objects.filter(Prefix='') will return filtered object name. OTH, `paginator` allow you to use JSONPath to do post-processing query.  Boto3 developer should able to give you clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

The S3 API supports a `prefix` on the `ListObjects` request that will filter the responses to include only those objects whose name matches the `prefix`.  So:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='foo/bar/fie/baz/'):
    # do something with obj here
```

Would only return objects whose name begins with the prefix `foo/bar/fie/baz/`.